# why almost complex manifold have $d = \mu + \bar{\mu} + \partial + \bar{\partial}$ , complex manifold only $\partial+\bar{\partial}$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $X$ be some almost complex manifold,with tangent bundle equipped with some complex structure $I$.

Then we know the exterior derivative decomposed into four part $d= \mu + \bar{\mu} + \partial + \bar{\partial}$ with $\mu $ component in $\mathcal{A}^{(p+2,q-1)}$ ,$\bar{\mu}$ component in $\mathcal{A}^{(p-1,q+2)}$.Where $\mathcal{A}^{p,q}$ means the differential form in type $(p,q)$.

I can't figure out the difference between complex manifold and almost complex manifold,we know on complex manifold $d = \partial +\bar{\partial}$.The proof is as follows,since:

$$d(f)=\sum_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} d x_{i}+\sum_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{i}} d y_{i}=\sum_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_{i}} d z_{i}+\sum_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}_{i}} d \bar{z}_{i}$$

we have $$d(fdz_{I}\wedge d\bar{z}_J) = \sum_k \partial_{z_k}{f}dz_k\wedge dz_{I}\wedge d\bar{z}_J +\sum_l\partial_{\bar{z}_l}{f}d\bar{z}_l\wedge dz_{I}\wedge d\bar{z}_J$$

Hence $d = \partial + \bar{\partial}$.

The question is why almost complex manifold has $\mu$ component?It looks the proof is almost the same?

Comment: I am not an expert, but my guess is that you cannot so easily write down complex coordinates $z,\bar z$ on a.c. $X$.

Comment: @Keshav  ,I agree,since coordinate $z$ is given by the standard complex structure,via the isomorphism $dx \mapsto dx + iI(dx) = dx +idy = dz$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that when you have an almost complex structure $J$, you can decompose any $1$-forms into type $(1,0)$ and type $(0,1)$ forms.  Locally, this gives a basis $e^1,\dots,e^n$ of $\mathcal{A}^{(1,0)}(U)$ but they are **not** of the form $\mathrm{d}z^1,\dots,\mathrm{d}z^n$ since there is no guarantee their dual $e_i\in \mathfrak{X}^{(1,0)}(U)$ are involutive to let you integrate for the coordinates $z^1,\dots,z^n$.  Indeed, if you decompose the $2$-form $\mathrm{d}e^i$ into its $(2,0)$-, $(1,1)$- and $(0,2)$-components
$$
\mathrm{d}e^i=a^i_{jk} e^j\wedge e^k+b^i_{j\bar{k}} e^j\wedge\overline{e^k}+c^i_{\bar{j}\bar{k}} \overline{e^j}\wedge\overline{e^k}
$$
By Frobenius's theorem, $J$ is integrable iff $c^i_{\bar{j}\bar{k}}=0$ for all $i,j,k$, or equivalently $\bar{\mu}=0$ (so $\mu=0$ too).

Comment: I couldn't judge whether you actually understand this correctly, but I am allowing much greater freedom of the basis $e^i$ than what you are alluded to.  Anyway, for your second question, I'm using Frobenius theorem in terms of differential ideal after taking conjugation to get $\mathrm{d}\overline{e^i}=\dots$.  The other terms having $\overline{e^j},\overline{e^k}$ in them would annihilate $T^{(1,0)}$ but the term $\overline{c^i_{\bar{j}\bar{k}}}e^j\wedge e^k$ don't give $0$ unless $c^i_{\bar{j}\bar{k}}=0$.  We don't need $e^i$ exact, e.g., $e^1=f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}z^1$ is allowed.

Comment: thank you,the set of 1 form $e^j = 1/2(dx_j- iI(dx_j))$ gives basis for $\mathcal{A}^{1,0}(U)$ correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be a local frame if you choose $x_j$ appropriately.  I am not assuming $e^j+\overline{e^j}$ is exact either.

Comment: There is no reason why our frame is that frame.